# Не выводить пустые записи wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет.
Вывожу отзывы товаров, но проблема в том, что выводятся записи без отзывов. Нужно, чтобы пропускались такие записи, у которых нет отзывов.
Слева на скриншоте это вывод поставщиков через произвольные посты, справа это отзывы товаров.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <div class="content-inner reviews-inner">
    <?php $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'suppliers',
        'suppress_filters' => 0,
    );
    global $product;
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach($posts as $post) { setup_postdata($post) ?>
    <div class="reviews-card">
        <div class="reviews-card-left">
            <div class="review-card-photo">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'large'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="reviews-card-rating">
            </div>
            <div class="review-card-name"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></div>
            <div class="review-card-activity"><?php the_field('suppliers__activity', $post->ID); ?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="reviews-card-review">
            <?php $comments = get_comments(array(
            'post_id' => $product->ID,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'status' => 'approve',
            'number' => 3
            ));

        foreach( $comments as $comment ) { ?>
            <div class="reviews-card-card">
                <div class="reviews-card-photo">
                    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); ?>" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="reviews-card-content">
                    <div class="reviews-card-title">
                        <?php echo $comment->post_title; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="reviews-card-meta">
                        <div class="reviews-card-time"><?php echo get_comment_date('d M Y'); ?></div>
                        <div class="reviews-card-rating">
                        <?php $rating = intval( get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true ) ); if ( $rating && wc_review_ratings_enabled() ) {
                            echo wc_get_rating_html( $rating ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
                        } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="reviews-card-text">
                        <?php echo $comment->comment_content;?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#reviews" class="review-card-link scroll-link btn-small">Смотреть все отзывы</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы посты, у которых нет комментариев не выводились, как на скриншоте можно увидеть пустые посты, их не нужно выводить

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
<div class="content-inner reviews-inner">
    <?php $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'comment_count',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'suppliers',
    );
    global $product;
    $posts = get_posts($args);

    foreach($posts as $post) { setup_postdata($post);

        $comments = get_comments(array(
            'post_id' => $product->ID,
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'status' => 'approve',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'number' => 3,
        )); ?>

    <?php if($comments) { ?>

    <div class="reviews-card">
        <div class="reviews-card-left">
            <div class="review-card-photo">
                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'large'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="reviews-card-rating">
            </div>
            <div class="review-card-name"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></div>
            <div class="review-card-activity"><?php the_field('suppliers__activity', $post->ID); ?></div>
        </div>

        <div class="reviews-card-review">

    <?php foreach( $comments as $comment ) { ?>
    
        <div class="reviews-card-card">
            <div class="reviews-card-photo">
                <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $comment ); ?>" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="reviews-card-content">
                <div class="reviews-card-title">
                    <?php echo $comment->post_title; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="reviews-card-meta">
                    <div class="reviews-card-time"><?php echo get_comment_date('d M Y'); ?></div>
                    <div class="reviews-card-rating">
                        <?php $rating = intval( get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true ) ); if ( $rating && wc_review_ratings_enabled() ) {
                            echo wc_get_rating_html( $rating ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
                        } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="reviews-card-text">
                    <?php echo $comment->comment_content;?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <?php } ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#reviews" class="review-card-link scroll-link btn-small">Смотреть все отзывы</a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <?php } } ?>

</div>
```